# How to skip iteration in JQ

Tags: jq

```
{   "items":[
    {
      "metadata":{"name":"127.0.0.1"},
      "status":{
        "capacity":{"cpu":3}
      }
    },
    {
      "metadata":{"name":"127.0.0.2"},
      "status":{
        "capacity":{"cpu":8}
      }
    }   ] }
```

I want to do following:

```
.items[] | if .metadata.name=="127.0.0.1" then {cpu: .status.capacity.cpu} else <<I want to skip>> end
```

I want skip if 1st continue is false

Required Output:

```
{"cpu":3}
```

Comment: Can you do this? Man who gives downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@aerofile-kite - Your first instinct is right.  There is no need to use `map` and in your case, it is probably more efficient not to use it.  Following your line of thought, you could write:

```
.items[]
| if .metadata.name=="127.0.0.1"
  then {cpu: .status.capacity.cpu}
  else empty
  end
```

or more succinctly:

```
  .items[]
  | select(.metadata.name=="127.0.0.1")
  | { cpu: .status.capacity.cpu }
```

Comment: Ok. Your answer solves my quest for skipping else part

Answer (score 2):

Use `map(select(...))`:

```
jq '.items|map(select(.metadata.name == "127.0.0.1"))|.[].status.capacity' items 
{
  "cpu": 3
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this